# experimental unit subject or organ piece?

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have an experiment where a a specific organ is taken from an animal. It is divided into 4 equal parts then each part is assigned a treatment.  Then another  organ is taken from a different animal and divided again into 4 equal parts and each part is assigned a treatment. I would like to know if there is an effect of treatment or time. What is the experimental unit the animal or the part of the organ? Would this be a repeated measures analysis or 2 factor ANOVA?

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: It is a continuous variable (levels of hormones).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the two main effects treatment group and time. If time is nominal scaled (i.e. t1, t2 ... tn) and your dependent variable is continuous you want to use a repeated measures ANOVA.